# What is the radius of convergence of this series $\sum_{i=0}^n \frac{n^{n}(2n)!}{(3n)!}x^{n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

What is the radius of convergence of this series:
$$\sum_{i=0}^n \frac{n^{n}(2n)!}{(3n)!}x^{n}$$

I thought it was somehow connected to Stirling-formulas but that didn't yield anything.

Comment: Try the [ratio test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test) and use $\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+1/n)^n = e$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the Cauchy - Hadamard formula, we get the radius of convergence as follows :
$$ R = \frac{1}{L^*} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \mid {\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}} \mid $$
$$ \therefore R = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n^n (2n)! (3n+3)!}{(3n)!(n+1)^{n+1}(2n+2)!} $$
$$ \therefore R = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n^n(3n+3)(3n+2)(3n+1)}{(n+1)^{n}(n+1)(2n+2)(2n+1)} $$
$$\therefore R = \lim_{n \to \infty} (\frac{n}{n+1})^n . \frac{3.3.3}{1.2.2}$$
$$\therefore R = \frac{27}{4} \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{(1+1/n)^n}$$ 
$$\therefore R = \frac{27}{4e}$$